# Check if timeout has deferred tasks Jasmine Unit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have been writing unit tests with Jasmine for AngularJs. Here is the plunker I have created to simulate the problem I am facing:

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/0fG6QnbFbZTVlMlZ7FsS)

My Unit test1:

```
describe('MyService', function () {
    var myService;
    beforeEach(module('timeoutUnitTest'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_MyService_, _$timeout_) {
        myService = _MyService_;
        timeout = _$timeout_;
    }));

     it('should set timeout for polling when not sent in', inject(function () {

        myService.getData(1,30)
         timeout.flush(10); 

    }));
});
```

My Unit test2 :

```
         it('should not set timeout for polling when not sent in', inject(function () {

            myService.getData(1)
             timeout.flush(10); 

        }));
    });
```

My Code :

```
angular.module('timeoutUnitTest').service('MyService',function($q,$timeout){
   function _getPrivateData(timeoutPeriod,id){
      if(timeoutPeriod && timeoutPeriod){
        $timeout(function(){
          console.log('in timeout task');
        },timeoutPeriod);
      }
      var def = $q.defer(); def.resolve('1');
      return def.promise;
   }

   function test(){
     var def = $q.defer();
     def.resolve(0);
     return def.promise;
   }

   function getData(id,timeoutPeriod){
    return test().then(_getPrivateData.bind(null,timeoutPeriod)).then(function(){
         return 2;
      });
   }

   return {
     getData : getData
   }

});
```

In above I am setting a timout task only of I pass timeout parameter to getData. 
According to my understanding :
1) When I pass timeout argument and call flush function also with some timeout parameter -  (Unit Test 1 )
Expectation : test should succeed and timeout should flush the set task
Actual : as per expectation

2) When I pass timeout argument and call the flush without some timeout -  (Unit Test 1 )
Expectation : test should fail and timeout should  throw error as the task is not set yet by the time flush is called. the reason for sending the timeout to flush itself.
Actual : as per expectation

3) When I **don't** pass timeout argument and call flush function also with some timeout parameter - (Unit Test 2 )
Expectation : test should fail and flush should throw the error as there is no timeout task set at all as timeout argument is undefined to getData
Actual : not per expectation and flush succeeds.

So Why the third test fails and flush doesn't throw the error?
In my real code flush **always** succeeds even when I don't send timeout parameter to getData and to flush as well. That is not correct.

Any help to understand the behavior of flush would be really helpful. Also main question is again how to write test to  make sure timeout is not setting the task and it is settting a task?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve based on what you describe vs. code shared.

Comment: @BradleyBraithwaite Sorry for confusion I have edited the question and  added code for the second unit test  3) case which actually fails as flush succeeds even if there is not any timeout task i am adding. When I don't pass the timeout parameter to my service the timeout task in MySevice's _getPrivateData is not set all all. Then why timeout.flush doesn't throw the error that there are no deferred tasks to flush.

Comment: Taking a few steps back from all this, what problem are you trying to solve? For example, in your plunker example, _getPrivateData doesn't get called at all when I run it!? I think the issues you are describing are attributed to running asynchronous unit tests due to the way you are using promises/$q.

Comment: @BradleyBraithwaite may be I didn't put correct code. I have mocked up an example as I can't put real code here. .it didn't get called because I didn't resolve the promise in test function. Now Basic problem is that I add a timeout task on a condition.if timeout parameter is sent it gets set other wise not. Now I want to test that if a timeout task is set or not in two different unit test. I have again updated the code

Comment: The problem you are seeing can be narrowed down to this: http://plnkr.co/edit/EoHdXpSD5MkbHx1QJl9K?p=preview It seems your use of $timeout in the tests is clashing with the way in which you are resolving the promises synchronously in the service code.

Comment: @BradleyBraithwaite Yes might be. However in real code I correctly resolve promises in similar fashion. where in actual code there is a $http call and i spy it and return fake resolved promise. How to test timeout where the task is set in some async call's then method?  Because of this i cant cover scenarios to test the code which sets the task